Assigning codes to a regular grid based on relative position
I need to assign UTM1km codes to a grid already have. I am trying to extract these codes from a UTM10x10 code I already have. A code of a given UTM10x10km is something like EG06. Each UTM10x10km polygon has 100 (or less if incomplete) 1x1km polygons. Within each UTM10x10km, the 1x1km polygon at left-low corner is 00, for example EG0060. The one at right-top corner must be 99, so EG0969. An example of an already existing area:

In red de 10km grid and, smaller, the regular 1km grid.
I have an empty UTM1x1km grid and I am trying to give to each polygon the UTM1x1km code using my UTM10x10km. I only need to fill the 4th and 6th digit of my UTM1x1km field by putting the correct number given the abovementioned rules.   My code looks like this so far:
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

arxiu_1x1 <- "C:/Users/usuari/Desktop/UTM/UTM1x1km_PPCC_v5_buits.gpkg"
arxiu_10x10 <- "C:/Users/usuari/Desktop/UTM/PPCC_utm10km_v3.gpkg"

polygons_1x1 <- st_read(arxiu_1x1)
polygons_10x10 <- st_read(arxiu_10x10)

polygons_1x1 <- st_transform(polygons_1x1, crs = 25831)
polygons_10x10 <- st_transform(polygons_10x10, crs = 25831)

# Calcular els centroides dels polígons de 1x1 km
centroids_1x1 <- polygons_1x1 %>%
  st_centroid() %>%
  st_as_sf()

centroids_1x1 <- centroids_1x1 %>%
  mutate(
    UTMX = st_coordinates(.)[, 1],  
    UTMY = st_coordinates(.)[, 2]   
  )


centroids_1x1 <- st_join(centroids_1x1, polygons_10x10, join = st_intersects)


centroids_1x1 <- centroids_1x1 %>%
  mutate(
    UTM1X1 = paste0(substr(UTMCODE, 1, 2),  # Les dues primeres lletres
                    substr(UTMCODE, 3, 3), "X", substr(UTMCODE, 5, 5), "X")  
  )


centroids_1x1 <- centroids_1x1 %>%
  group_by(UTMCODE) %>%  # Agrupar per cada bloc de 10x10 km
  arrange(desc(UTMY), UTMX) %>% 
    pos1 = rep(0:9, each = 10)[1:n()],  # Assignar valors per al 4t dígit (de 0 a 9)
    pos2 = rep(0:9, times = 10)[1:n()]  # Assignar valors per al 6è dígit (de 0 a 9)
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(
    UTM1X1 = paste0(substr(UTM1X1, 1, 3), pos1, substr(UTM1X1, 5, 5), pos2)  
  )

resultats_final <- polygons_1x1 %>%
  st_join(select(centroids_1x1, UTM1X1), join = st_intersects)

output_path <- "C:/Users/usuari/Desktop/UTM1x1km_resultat.gpkg"
st_write(resultats_final, output_path, delete_layer = TRUE)

This codes makes de job but the relative order within each UTM10x10km is wrong!

Without your gpkg files and without seeing what is wrong with your "relative order" here its hard to help. Can you edit your question and post a link to your GPKG and explain or show what's going wrong?

Done: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1PjXZIEna4b155Xp5TMul-fT3tMT1Cd6b?usp=drive_link Thanks!

Your source GPKG isn't totally empty - some of the cells do have valud UTM1X1 values, eg after reading from the GPKG look at polygons_1x1[6000,], it has "CG7792". Are you just trying to fill in the missing ones? Also can you go through your code and work out at each stage if its what you expect or not, and print bits of the table or make some plots to show? Its hard to chase down "the relative order is wrong" otherwise...

It also seems you are overcomplicating this by doing an intersection with the other grid. Just using the centroids of the 1x1 cells in UTM coordinates and doing some arithmetic on the values can give you the grid cell names and numbers -

Thanks Spacedman. Yes, exactly, part of my grid is already full but can be deleted and filled again maybe? The use of the centroids it is because I am not sure how to do the arithmetics you mention so the grid is executed as I need and showed in the picture. My approach was to use the information in the UTM10km grid because I can extract from it 4/6 digits and somehow try to manage to get the 2 remaining ones.  If you have a more arithmetic approach and less geographical I will be grateful too!

First let's read the fine 1km grid in, transform, and add the X and Y centroids as new columns:
makegrid <- function(f="./UTM1x1km_PPCC_v5_buits.gpkg"){
    grid1k = st_read(f)

    grid1k = st_transform(grid1k, 25831)
    grid1k = cbind(grid1k, st_coordinates(st_centroid(grid1k)))

    return(grid1k)
}

Next, function that returns a two-letter label given an X and Y coordinate:
gridlabel = function(X,Y){
    Xletter = function(X){
        pos = X %/% 100000
        LETTERS[pos]
    }
    Yletter = function(Y){
        pos = (Y-3900000) %/% 100000
        LETTERS[pos]
    }
    paste(Xletter(X), Yletter(Y), sep="")
}

quick test to see if our computed two-letter codes match the ones that do exist in the supplied grid file:
> labels = gridlabel(grid1k$X, grid1k$Y)
> head(labels)
[1] "DG" "DG" "DG" "DG" "DG" "DG"
> all(labels == substr(grid1k$UTM10x10,1,2), na.rm=TRUE)
[1] TRUE

Good good. Next we need a function to basically reverse that so we know where the rest of our coordinates start from...
labelpos = function(label){
    cbind(x=(match(substr(label, 1, 1), LETTERS) ) * 100000,
          y=3900000 + match(substr(label, 2,2), LETTERS) * 100000)
}

Then check we get the right origin point for cell labels:
> labelpos(c("DG","EH"))
         x       y
[1,] 4e+05 4600000
[2,] 5e+05 4700000

Looks fine, each step through the alphabet of the first letter adds 1e5 to the X coordinate, and similar for the second latter. WARNING This assumes your grid letters use all the letters of the alphabet! If the system doesn't use "I" or "O" then this will fail when it gets to cells out there.
Now finally wrap it up into a single function that returns a 1km grid cell given any coordinate:
grid1kname = function(X, Y){
    code = gridlabel(X,Y)
    codeorigin = labelpos(code)
    dx = X - codeorigin[,1]
    dy = Y - codeorigin[,2]
    X1k = sprintf("%02d",dx %/% 1000)
    Y1k = sprintf("%02d",dy %/% 1000)
    paste(code, X1k, Y1k,sep="")
}

Test by comparing computed cell codes with ones in the supplied data...
> test = grid1kname(grid1k$X, grid1k$Y)
> all(test == grid1k$UTM1X1, na.rm=TRUE)
[1] FALSE

OH NO! They don't all match even when I drop the cells in the data that had missing codes... Where?
> which(test != grid1k$UTM1X1)
[1] 10578 10654
> plot(grid1k$geom[which(test != grid1k$UTM1X1)])


Okay those two are weird cells that aren't even square. There's a few odd "cells" in the data with minuscule areas that look like cropping areas, and these two seem to have different codes to what my function computes probably because they are on a cell boundary.
So apart from that, my function should do your task. If you want the coarser grid names then extract parts from this using substr.

working perfectly with grid1k <- makegrid()
grid1k$UTM1X1 <- mapply(grid1kname, grid1k$X, grid1k$Y)
output_path <- "C:/Users/usuari/Desktop/UTM1x1km_resultat.gpkg"
st_write(grid1k, output_path, delete_layer = TRUE)
